# Creating Cognito User Pool With Custom Domain name from AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I'm trying to creating Cognito user pool with a custom domain name through AWS CDK. I manage to get everyting working untill to the point where I needed to create an `A` record in the `Rout53` hosted zone. I searched through all the documents but coudn't find a way to do that. Following is my code. Any help would be much appriciated.

```
      const cfnUserPool = new CfnUserPool(this, 'MyCognitoUserPool', {
            userPoolName: 'MyCognitoUserPool',
            adminCreateUserConfig: {
                allowAdminCreateUserOnly: false
            },
            policies: {
                passwordPolicy: {
                    minimumLength: 8,
                    requireLowercase: true,
                    requireNumbers: true,
                    requireSymbols: true,
                    requireUppercase: true,
                    temporaryPasswordValidityDays: 30
                }
            },
            usernameAttributes: [
                UserPoolAttribute.EMAIL
            ],
            schema: [
                {
                    attributeDataType: 'String',
                    name: UserPoolAttribute.EMAIL,
                    mutable: true,
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    attributeDataType: 'String',
                    name: UserPoolAttribute.FAMILY_NAME,
                    mutable: false,
                    required: true
                },
                {
                    attributeDataType: 'String',
                    name: UserPoolAttribute.GIVEN_NAME,
                    mutable: false,
                    required: true
                }
            ]
        });

      const cognitoAppDomain = new CfnUserPoolDomain(this, "PigletAuthDomainName", {
            domain: authDomainName,
            userPoolId: cfnUserPool.ref,
            customDomainConfig: {
                certificateArn: 'ACM Certificate arn'
            }
        });

    /* 
      TODO: Create an A record from the created cnfUserPoolDomain
    */
```

Everything works up untill to this point. Now the question is how to create an A record using the `CfnUserPoolDomain`

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: User Pools don’t have an IP address, so you can’t set up any DNS records like that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @madu, I modified my answer to use a CustomResource, and it is working very nicely.

Answer (score 15):

## Update May 2020

The [UserPoolDomain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cognito.UserPoolDomain.html) construct has been extended and a [UserPoolDomainTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53-targets.UserPoolDomainTarget.html) was added to provide this functionality.

Now, all you need to do is the following:

```js
const userPoolDomain = new cognito.UserPoolDomain(this, 'UserPoolDomain', {
  userPool,
  customDomain: {
    domainName: authDomainName,
    certificate,
  },
});

new route53.ARecord(this, 'UserPoolCloudFrontAliasRecord', {
  zone: hostedZone,
  recordName: authDomainName,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new route53_targets.UserPoolDomainTarget(userPoolDomain)),
});
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but doesn't I still get Was not able to resolve the root domain, please ensure an A record exists for the root domain.  The UserPoolDomain is created before the A Record

Comment: Yes. The `UserPoolDomainTarget` construct requires a valid A record for the root domain. See [Cognito Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html#cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain-prereq). You may add a [resource depedency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#resource-options) on an A-record created by your CDK app (e.g. using `someARecord.node.addDependency`), or create the custom domain conditionally (e.g. using a feature flag/prop set to false during the first deployment)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had an A record for www.mydomain.com, but not domain.com.  Works now.

Comment: When my  `hostedZone` is from `route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneId`, i get an error: `Error: HostedZone.fromHostedZoneId doesn't support "zoneName"`... I'm using `1.109.0` CDK packages

Comment: Looks like using `.fromHostedZoneAttributes` works instead

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem, It looks like CloudFormation does not have a return parameter for the CfnUserPoolDomain AliasTarget. Which means the cdk can not provide this parameter either.

I ended up implementing it using the AWS SDK (`npm install aws-sdk`) and getting the value using the APIs:

---

Update: The better solution is to use the [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html). You can see a detailed example in [aws/aws-cdk (#6787)](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6787#issuecomment-601432895):

```
const userPoolDomainDescription = new customResources.AwsCustomResource(this, 'user-pool-domain-description', {
  onCreate: {
    physicalResourceId: 'user-pool-domain-description',
    service: 'CognitoIdentityServiceProvider',
    action: 'describeUserPoolDomain',
    parameters: {
      Domain: userPoolDomain.domain
    }
  }
});

const dnsName = userPoolDomainDescription.getData('DomainDescription.CloudFrontDistribution').toString();

// Route53 alias record for the UserPoolDomain CloudFront distribution
new route53.ARecord(this, 'UserPoolDomainAliasRecord', {
  recordName: userPoolDomain.domain,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias({
    bind: _record => ({
      hostedZoneId: 'Z2FDTNDATAQYW2', // CloudFront Zone ID
      dnsName: dnsName,
    }),
  }),
  zone,
})
```

Comment: i'm not sure how to use it, since the dnsName is a token, aws-sdk cannot use it directly. do I need to create another stack that will run after this one and pass this value somehow (CfnOutput?)

Comment: What do you mean with: 'the dnsName is a token'? Have you tried using the AwsCustomResource as in the post?

Comment: Yeah, im using AwsCustomResource just like you showed, and I know it works, since if I try to use the value of dnsName (wrongfully) creating a normal A record, then I get an error that the cloudfront alias name is not a valid ip. this means that it works. but, when I try to use dnsName in a call to aws-sdk to create an alias record, I get an error about its value, which is: ${Token[Default.DomainDescription.CloudFrontDistribution.68]}. this is a cdk token, which will be resolved later. aws-sdk is not aware of that and tries to use the explicit value. my question is, how do you use it?

Comment: by "this means that it works", I meant to say that the error is actually showing the real value of the alias target that matches the one showing in the user pool UI - domain name section

Comment: @RoyCa see the latest edits above and/or have a look at the full example over in https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6787#issuecomment-601432895 to see a fully worked example of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get around it. Assuming you have a `stack.yaml` that you deploy with a CI tool, say through bash:

```sh
THE_STACK_NAME="my-cognito-stack"
THE_DOMAIN_NAME="auth.yourveryowndomain.org"

# get the alias target
# notice that it will be empty upon first launch (chicken and the egg problem)
ALIAS_TARGET=$(aws cognito-idp describe-user-pool-domain --domain ${THE_DOMAIN_NAME} | grep CloudFrontDistribution | cut -d \" -f4)

# create/update the deployment CloudFormation stack
# notice the AliasTarget parameter (which can be empty, it's okay!)
aws cloudformation deploy --stack-name ${THE_STACK_NAME} --template-file stack.yaml --parameter-overrides AliasTarget=${ALIAS_TARGET} DomainName=${THE_DOMAIN_NAME}
```

The `stack.yaml` minimal version (remember to fill the `UserPool` config):

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: auth.yourveryowndomain.org
    Description: The domain name to use to serve this project.

  ZoneName:
    Type: String
    Default: yourveryowndomain.org
    Description: The hosted zone name coming along with the DomainName used.

  AliasTarget: # no default value, can be empty
    Type: String
    Description: The UserPoolDomain alias target.

Conditions: # here's "the trick"
  HasAliasTarget: !Not [!Equals ['', !Ref AliasTarget]]

Resources:
  Certificate:
    Type: "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate"
    Properties: 
      DomainName: !Ref ZoneName
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: !Ref ZoneName
          ValidationDomain: !Ref ZoneName
      SubjectAlternativeNames:
        - !Ref DomainName

  UserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      [... fill that with your configuration! ...]

  UserPoolDomain:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref UserPool
      Domain: !Ref DomainName
      CustomDomainConfig:
        CertificateArn: !Ref Certificate

  DnsRecord: # if AliasTarget parameter is empty, well we just can't do that one!
    Condition: HasAliasTarget # and here's how we don't do it when we can't
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Sub "${ZoneName}."
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !Ref AliasTarget
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false
        # HostedZoneId value for CloudFront is always this one
        # see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html
        HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
      Name: !Ref DomainName
      Type: A
```

Be aware CloudFormation conditions are not "a trick" at all: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html. We simply use it as a trick along with the *"first launch won't do it all"* to get around our scenario.

Kinda weird, but only for the first run! Launch it again: everything is fine.

---

PS: can't wait to avoid all that by simply having the CloudFrontDistribution alias target directly in the `AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain` return values!!